# FFMPEG shows error message

Tags: ffmpeg

I am pretty new to ffmpeg, sorry. I am trying to compose a video from individual images. The images have size 2667 x 1500.

The following command gives me an error:

```
"/usr/bin/ffmpeg" -y -f concat -safe 0 -i "/home/abc/def/data/tmp/gVQO7wUc.txt" -vf "pad=ih*16/9:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,scale=1920:1080:flags=lanczos" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart "/home/abc/def/data/tmp/964MX26P.mp4"
```

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, concat, from '/home/showroom/companyshowroom/data/tmp/gVQO7wUc.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 2667x1500 [SAR 7874:7874 DAR 889:500], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0x14466c0] Input area 0:0:2667:1500 not within the padded area 0:0:2666:1500 or zero-sized
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0x14466c0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_0
Error opening filters!
```

The input file looks as follows:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file '/home/abc/def/uploads/slides/5fca45f5ad365/slide_001.png'
duration 9
file '/home/abc/def/uploads/slides/5fca45f5ad365/slide_005.png'
duration 2
file '/home/abc/def/uploads/slides/5fca45f5ad365/slide_006.png'
duration 2
file '/home/abc/def/uploads/slides/5fca45f5ad365/slide_011.png'
duration 18
file '/home/abc/def/uploads/slides/5fca45f5ad365/slide_021.png'
```

I assume the issue is that the images are have "odd" sizes - should be even only? Is there a way to scale them down within FFMPEG? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only pad frames to a size as large as or larger than the source size. In your case, 16/9 multiplier of 1500 is 2666.66 which is rounded down to 2666 and hence smaller than source width. Since your source aspect is so close, just skip the pad.

`"/usr/bin/ffmpeg" -y -f concat -safe 0 -i "/home/abc/def/data/tmp/gVQO7wUc.txt" -vf "scale=1920:1080:flags=lanczos,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart "/home/abc/def/data/tmp/964MX26P.mp4"`